# Calling script and passing value from called script

Tags: perl, system, execute

I have one script i'm trying to call from another script, passing the information from the script that is being called to the calling script. When i use do or require it runs through but doesnt pass the value.

ex.

I have the following line at the bottom of the script that i am calling

### called script.pl

print "   $hold IS VALUE\n";

which prints me the value of hold.

I then start the calling script with:

### calling_script.pl

require 'acc_option.pl';
print "HOLD PASSED IS $hold\n";

but the variable hold doesnt print.

Whats the best way to call this script instead of putting everything on one long ass page?

Answer (score 3):

You have started down the right path, but are still a ways off.  You should be using modules and the [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) statment, not code and the [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/funcitons/require.html) statement.  You should try reading [`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) and [`perldoc perlmodlib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html#Modules%3a-Creation%2c-Use%2c-and-Abuse), but the general gist is:

1. decompose your process into functions
2. group those functions by what they do
3. put the groups of functions into modules
4. write a script that uses the modules and calls the functions

Think of the script as a skeleton and the functions as fleshing out the skeleton.

Here is a simple module and a script that uses it:

ExampleModule.pm:

```
package ExampleModule;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Exporter';

our @EXPORT_OK  = qw/do_first_thing do_second_thing do_third_thing/;

sub do_first_thing {
    my ($thing) = @_;

    return $thing + 1;
}

sub do_second_thing {
    my ($thing) = @_;

    return $thing + 1;
}

sub do_third_thing {
    my ($thing) = @_;

    return $thing + 1;
}

1;
```

example.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use ExampleModule qw/do_first_thing do_second_thing do_third_thing/;

my $thing = 0;

$thing = do_first_thing($thing);
$thing = do_second_thing($thing);
$thing = do_third_thing($thing);

print "$thing\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how $hold was declared.

If it was lexically declared (with "my $hold...") then you can't get at it directly - it's only accessible within the scope of called_script.pl.

If it's dynamically scoped (local $hold, or our $hold) then you should be able to get at it by prefixing it with the package it was declared under (so if it's in "package Foo;" you can get at it as $Foo::hold").

That said...

You generally don't want to mess around passing variables between scripts. Storing state in global variables can make for some nasty debugging sessions.

As a first step you might want to encapsulate accessing $hold inside a subroutine so in called_script.pl you have something like:

```
sub is_on_hold { return $hold };
```

which will return $hold when called (I'm assuming here that $hold is some kind of boolean state indicator. If it isn't name your subroutine in an appropriately intention revealing way :-)

If you describe how you're trying to use $hold in a bit more detail folk might be able to give some more specific advice on a better way of doing your task.